# Replace SSR10DD with SSR25DA

Tags: ac, dc, solid-state-relay

I have a machine with damaged Solid State Relay (SSR) designed to work with DC, there is not available a replacement and what we have is another SSR but for AC. Both of them of course are controlled with a DC signal from 5 to 34 VDC. I already placed the SSR10DA instead of the other with no luck. Is there any way I can make it work? The SSR will supply 24VDC to the solenoid of a electric magnet. The original part # is JGX-1572F 030-10A; the replace is a generic SSR-25DA

Comment: Is it original PSU? How many Amps rating is it? The original SSR is for DC, and must not be replaced with an AC SSR unless you supply 24Vac and rectify after the SSR.

Comment: mybe if i add some estra hardaware to make it work? original is rated to 10A

Answer (score 0):

No. AC SSRs use triacs to switch the load. Triacs, once switched on, remain on until the current falls to very close to zero. Because you are switching DC the triac will never switch off.

You *might* get it to work with a solenoid if you use a 24 V power supply made of a transformer and full-wave rectifier with no smoothing capacitor.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIqV5x.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Either of the schemes above provide a possible solution.*

Switching on the low-voltage side gives the possibility of switching several solenoid valves from the one transformer.

Comment: i was thinkung on something like that, inclusive if i conect the SSR25DA to the 220VAC of the new power supply

Comment: See the update.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to substitute if the original part is readily [available](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08RDW61P6).

However it must be rated for your voltage and 40A with suitable heatsink if load is high and for DC only.